# Change the date and time of one app

Tags: applications

I have installed a 7 day trial app. Changing the date and time in the phone can "evade" the version and trial and continue to use it. But this privates the fact that I've busted in every app. I wanted to know if it was possible to change the date of a single app even by changing the source code of 'App. I hope someone helps me and thank you in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is unethical

Comment: Might be time for a meta topic to decide whether we want to support unethical behaviors here.

Comment: [Let's discuss on Meta.](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2321)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107814/discussion-on-question-by-antonio-lopardo-change-the-date-and-time-of-one-app).

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK this is possible only if you have Xposed framework (hooking another app).

Take a look at [Per App Hacking](http://repo.xposed.info/module/org.t2k269.perapphacking). Its description reads

> 5. Allow set a fake time to fake an app to a specific time just like time machine. Time format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI